# Can I Swap Out Dell Desktop Power Cable

Tags: power

I accidentally stepped on my desktop power cable on my Dell XPS desktop.

The warning on the insert (not the manual) said to replace it if damaged.

Can I use the power cable from my old desktop instead, or do I need to purchase it specially from Dell?

Comment: so long as you don't break the plug or socket, stepping - even jumping -  on the actual wire itself is not going to cause any damage at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a simple cable and has the same physical plug connection, of course you can.  Most connections are a 3 prong type, sort of a D shape.

Comment: https://files.cablewholesale.com/hires/10w1-012.jpg - If the socket on the back of your PC looks like this fits, then you can use any cord that looks like this.  This is a ubiquitous cord/socket.

Comment: That is my power cable!!  The old one seems to be working.  No issues yet.